# using htaccess rewrite dynamic urls & category url

Tags: .htaccess

I want to know how to match a dynamic URL to a static URL using htaccess. but its's work from one RewriteRule but it doesn't work with second RewriteRule. How can i fix this.

I want it like this

`contact.php` to `example.com/contact`

`category.php?url=some-url` to `example.com/some-url`

My htaccess file

```
<Files .htaccess>
  order allow,deny
</Files>

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ category.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your approach. Most important: you appear to have understood the logic of rewriting rules the wrong way round...

Here is an example to get you started, you probably with have to adapt it to your specific setup:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ $1.php [END]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)url=(.+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?category\.php$ /%1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: 1st rule is working but not work with category links.. how can i fix it..

Comment: The rule is fine, it does what you asked. So most likely your actually situation is different from what you described. I suggest you add a precise example of what request should get rewritten to what resource internally.